# How to increase Python chaterbot's confidence on an answer programmatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot, chatterbot

I am working on Python library called Chatterbot. When I am getting a response how can I programmatically increase the confidence on it so that it will answer the same answer if same kind of question is posted to it again. In short how am I supposed to tell the chatbot that this is the right response and that's not the correct answer else it will be assuming a wrong answer to be correct one and increasing the confidence on it. 
For your information, I am able to get the response's confidence but increment in the confidence is not working as it is showing the same confidence every time.
My code as follows-

```
while True:
    request = str(input(username+": "))
    list_of_words = request.split(' ')
    for i in list_of_words:
        if i in happy_list:
            happy_count += 1
        elif i in sad_list:
            sad_count += 1
    if request.strip() != 'bye' and request.strip() != 'Bye' and request.strip() != 'ok bye' and request.strip() != 'see you' and request.strip() != 'see ya':
        response = bot.get_response(request)
        print("Joe: ",response)
        print(response.confidence)
        response.confidence = response.confidence + 0.1
        if happy_count >= 4 or sad_count >= 4:
            if happy_count >= 4:
                print("Joe: You seems to be very happy today",username)
                happy_count = 0
            elif sad_count >=4:
                print("Joe: What happened? Are you upset",username,"?")
                sad_count = 0
    else:
        print("Joe: Ya taddah")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works -->

```
class mdy:
def __init__(self, msg, rep):
    self.msg = msg
    self.rep = rep

def match(self):
    lowMsg = self.msg.lower()
    lowRep = self.rep.lower()
    lenMsg = len(self.msg.split(' '))
    lenRep = len(self.rep.split(' '))
    count = 0

    # Count
    for i in lowMsg.split(' '):
        if i in lowRep.split(' '):
            count = count + 1
    # Math
    percent = int(count/lenRep*100)
    if percent >= 60:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But instead of using reply, use the question :-)